# How to Android Self Managed Mode in react native callkeep?

Tags: android, react-native

Hye , i am using react-native-agora for one-to-one audio call in my application. for showing the incoming call UI, i am using react-native-callkeep. but the default callkeep UI is same as the android phone call UI. so,to differentiate between the two, i want to make my own UI using callkeep Android Self Managed Mode feature of callkeep library . in my case, showIncomingCallUi event is not firing when getting incoming call. i would highly appreciate for your help.

Version are as follow-
"react": "17.0.2",
"react-native": "0.67.3",
"react-native-agora": "^3.7.0",
"react-native-callkeep": "4.3.2",

Adding listener like this in separate file:-
RNCallKeep.addEventListener('showIncomingCallUi', ({ handle, callUUID, name }) => {
console.log('showIncomingCallUi', handle, 'callUUID-----', callUUID, 'name-----', name);
});

how to return the UI from this separate file to my component ?

Comment: anyone knows the answer ??

Comment: https://github.com/react-native-webrtc/react-native-callkeep#android-self-managed-mode 3rd bullet point

Answer (score 0):

Please verify if you have followed all the [installation and set-up instructions](https://github.com/react-native-webrtc/react-native-callkeep/blob/master/docs/android-installation.md#android-common-step-installation) for react-native-callkeep
Implement RNCallKeep with self-managed: true, you can show your custom UI for calls using this.

Here is the [setup guide](https://github.com/react-native-webrtc/react-native-callkeep#android-self-managed-mode) for the same